# Why am I getting two diferent outputs with my python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def kaka(name):
    r=''
    for ch in name:

        r=r+ch*3
    return r
```

Output:

```
>>> kaka('Mississippi')
>>> 'MMMiiissssssiiissssssiiippppppiii'
```

But for this code:

```
def kaka(name):   
    for ch in name:

        r=''
        r=r+ch*3
    return r
```

I am getting output as: `iii`

Comment: You can debug this by checking or printing `r` at each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in your second code you're re-assigning `r` back to the empty string `''`. Thus you only get the final character multiplied 3 times (which for Mississippi is `i`).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 2 different outputs because in the first code you are initialising the value of r i.e r = '' outside the for loop and in the second program you are initialising value of r inside the for loop.